# aws cdk golang, apply cfnCondition to all child resources created by default by awsec2.NewVpc

Tags: go, aws-cdk

I am work on creating an AWS CloudFormation template using AWS CDK with golang.
When I use the `awsec2.NewVpc` function, it is creating a vpc and its children like subnets, route table gatway etc, but can I apply Cfncondition for each resource created by default?

I am able to create condition only for VPC by below code but not for child resource:

```golang
(vpc.Node().DefaultChild().(awsec2.CfnVPC)).CfnOptions().SetCondition(cond)
```

Comment: You can use a CDK Aspect to apply it to all children.

Comment: thank you gshpychka, can you please provide one example or sample code

Comment: Try checking the CDK documentation on Aspects.